# Do any non-anglophone countries plan to introduce English as an official language?

Tags: languages

Is there currently a country (or have there been such countries in the past) where the government is planning to introduce English as the official language, despite the fact that the local population is not Anglophone and has never been under Anglophone colonial rule?

Comment: Singapour comes to mind.

Comment: @Bregalad Singapore wasn't a British colony per se but it was a British trading post for many decades.

Comment: Imperial Japan after the Meiji Restoration comes to mind http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/119/why-did-meiji-consider-switching-from-japanese-to-english

Comment: [Singapore was a British colony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straits_Settlements)

Comment: Some have suggested it for Sweden, but it's a fringe view.

Comment: Does anyone know whether Hawai'i counted, pre-axenation? I can't find good evidence either way.

Comment: Not official, but I'd say that in Switzerland, use of English is more common than at least two of the four official languages (Italian & Romansh), and perhaps even ahead of French.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Rwanda is such a country, having made the switch from French, the colonial language under Belgian rule, to English, in 2008.

The country has also joined the Commonwealth of Nations, despite never having been subject to the British crown.

I'm unaware of any country with current plans to follow in Rwanda's footsteps.

Comment: Rwanda didn't "switch" from French to English: they "added" English as national language. Rwanda did so because of the huge amount English-speaking Ugandese refugees during the 2nd half of the 20th century.

Answer (score 3):

Tonga's official languages are [Tongan and English](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/tn.html). Tonga was under British influence for a long time, but it [was never a British colony, having become a protectorate only](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-pacific-16197014), though it later joined the Commonwealth of Nations. The Tongan monarchy [was never abolished](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonga).